# Could a dependency use app permissions without declaring?

Tags: android

**My app**: has declared and used Contact Permissions.

**Dependency**: Does not declare Contact Permission in manifest file

Can dependency access to Contacts if user approved this permission from my app?

Comment: Yes. Manifest files across the project are essentially [merged](https://developer.android.com/build/manage-manifests)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They can. But it doesn't necessarily mean they will be granted. Some permissions require the user's explicit confirmation. So as long as you're handling the permission properly, your app and the dependency you're using should be fine.